# cron.daily not working for some shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron

I have some shell scripts that I have symlinked into `/etc/cron.daily`.

When I run the script as root it completes without any errors and do what needs to get done. I even added

```
source $HOME/.bash_profile
```

to the scripts but to no avail. The scripts use git and curl to update packages daily.

When I try `run-parts /etc/cron.daily/` it never completes.

Files inside /etc/cron.daily:

```
 check_updates -> /opt/devops/automation/server/utilities/check_updates.sh
 etckeeper
 install-external_utilities -> /opt/devops/automation/server/utilities/install-external_utilities.sh
 logrotate
 lynis_updates
```

Comment: Is there any chance of getting to see the script? Is the `git` or `curl` commands using any form of authentication that requires e.g. the SSH agent or interaction with a user?

Comment: Make sure to provide absolute paths to programs you are running in the script (`/usr/bin/curl` instead of `curl`)

Comment: @Panki It would be a bit odd if `/usr/bin` was not part of `$PATH` already, and I probably opt for adding it (and any other needed directory) to the end of `$PATH` in the script rather than using absolute paths everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I added the below to both scripts, I realised only the one had the entry in it. After that the 2 scripts completed with testing by run-parts.

```
# Import Env
source $HOME/.bash_profile
```

## Update

Even the fix above did not work reliably. I tried various recommendations and eventually settled to update my shebang.

```
#!/bin/bash -l
```

Just don't use that for a script that will load as part of a user's login.